# How to make a text carousel with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website. This is my JQuery, CSS, and part of my HTML:

```js
var featureDisplay;
var featureUnderline;
var features = [
  "comprehensive moderation", "utility commands", "music commands", "fun commands", "game integrations", "social system"
];
var featureID = 0;

function updateFeature() {
  var pushinFeatureDisplay = featureDisplay.clone();
  pushinFeatureDisplay.appendTo(featureDisplay.parent());
  pushinFeatureDisplay.text(features[featureID]);
  pushinFeatureDisplay.css("opacity", 0);
  pushinFeatureDisplay.css("margin-left", -pushinFeatureDisplay.width());
  pushinFeatureDisplay.animate({
    opacity: 1,
    marginLeft: -(pushinFeatureDisplay.width() * 0.5)
  }, 1000);
  var oldFeatureUnderline = featureUnderline.clone();
  oldFeatureUnderline.prependTo(featureUnderline.parent());
  oldFeatureUnderline.animate({
    width: 0
  }, 1000);
  featureUnderline.prependTo($(".feature-box")[featureID]);
  featureUnderline.css("width", 0);
  featureUnderline.animate({
    width: featureUnderline.parent().find(".feature-title").first().innerWidth()
  }, 1000);
  featureDisplay.animate({
    opacity: 0,
    marginLeft: (pushinFeatureDisplay.width() * 0.25)
  }, 1000, function() {
    featureDisplay.text(features[featureID++]);
    if (featureID >= features.length) featureID = 0;
    featureDisplay.css("opacity", 1);
    featureDisplay.css("margin-left", -(pushinFeatureDisplay.width() * 0.5));
    pushinFeatureDisplay.remove();
    oldFeatureUnderline.remove();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("I did the thing!");
  featureDisplay = $("#feature-display");
  featureUnderline = $("<div class='feature-underline'></div>");
  setTimeout(updateFeature, 1000);
  setInterval(updateFeature, 2500);
});
```

```css
h4 {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #00cc99;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.large-text {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.information-main {
  width: 66%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.bot-avatar {
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
.button-panel {
  text-align: center;
}
.button-panel a {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 2px solid #00cc99;
  color: #00cc99;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
}
.button-panel a:hover {
  background-color: #00cc99;
  color: #fafafa;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.feature-display {
  color: #00cc99;
  position: absolute;
}
.feature-row {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.feature-box {
  width: 33%;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.feature-title {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #00cc99;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.feature-description {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.feature-underline {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  background-color: #00cc99;
  border-radius: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div class="information-main">
  <img src="./JARVIS_files/JARVIS.png" class="bot-avatar">
  <br>
  <span class="large-text">JARVIS is an adaptable, multipurpose bot for Discord. Features include </span>
  <br>
  <span class="large-text feature-display" id="feature-display" style="opacity: 1; margin-left: -268.5px;">social system</span>
</div>
```

When I open it in my browser I don't even get a pop up. 
I am trying to make the words slide in and out. I saved it from Aethex.xyz and edited it. I want it to be like on that website. Even when I download the exact source of the website and don't edit it, it still doesn't work. I am new to HTML so please do not freak out if it is something stupid.

UPDATE: I've come back almost a year later now, and I've actually figured out what I'm doing so sorry to anyone who thought this was a stupid question (it was :)).

Comment: Just running your snippet here shows you a crucial missing dependency: jQuery.

Comment: Are you pulling in jQuery? I dont see your import statements. .ready() is a jQuery function and requires the library in order to work.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: **Best title ever**

Comment: Posting code is good, but please don't just dump your code and say "FIX IT". Spend a few minutes describing your problem and you'll find people will give you much better suggestions (and will be a whole lot nicer too :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a crucial part: jQuery.

Add this: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>`

Also, if you download it directly, you'll still be missing several items. In their code, they call their scripts in this fashion: `<script src="/js/odometer.min.js"></script>`.

You have to modify it for your own use:
`<script src="https://aethex.xyz/js/odometer.min.js"></script>`

Add the `https://aethex.xyz/js/odometer.min.js` to every script, and it should work